# How to use AngularJS Decorators to disable a button in Html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using blur admin theme in which i would like to use decorators to hide a button.Instead of directly making changes in their html i would like to use decorators and disable a button but i couldn't able to hide a button can anyone tell me how to disable a button using decorators.

Html:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="pager ba-wizard-pager">
        <li class="previous">
        <button  ng-disabled="$baWizardController.isFirstTab()" ng-click="$baWizardController.previousTab()" type="button" class=" btn btn-primary">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&larr;</span> {{ 'SECURE.NEW.PREVIOUS' | translate}}
        </button>
        </li>
        <li class="next">
        <button ng-disabled="$baWizardController.isLastTab()" ng-click="$baWizardController.nextTab()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
         {{ 'SECURE.NEW.NEXT' | translate}}
        <span aria-hidden="true">&rarr;</span></button></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Controller:

```
vm.isLastTab = function () {
  return vm.tabNum == vm.tabs.length - 1 ;
};
```

Decorator used:

```
function wizardConfig($provide) {
  $provide.decorator("baWizardDirective", function($delegate, $controller) {
    var directive = $delegate[0];

    var controllerName = directive.controller;
    directive.controller = function($scope) {
      angular.extend(this, $controller(controllerName, {$scope: $scope}));
      $scope.name = "from the decorator now";
    };

    return $delegate;
  });
}
```

Comment: I guess your function which you have called inside the ng-disabled must return value as boolean true or false

Comment: @TaylorRahul it is the default function used.i would like to use decorator  for it

Answer (score 0):

You should have access to the directive's link function.

Take a look a this blog post:

http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/09/experiment-decorating-directives/

Also the docs:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/decorators

```
function wizardConfig($provide) {
    $provide.decorator("baWizardDirective", function($delegate, $controller){
    var directive = $delegate[0];

    var link = function updatedLinkFunction(scope, element, attrs) {
       // conditionally disable element
    }

    var controllerName = directive.controller;
    directive.controller = function($scope) {
      angular.extend(this, $controller(controllerName, {$scope: $scope}));
      $scope.name = "from the decorator now";
    };

    directive.compile = function() {
       return function(scope, element, attrs) {
         link.apply(this, arguments);
       };
    };

    return $delegate;
   });
}
```